# How to Map an object contains other object with @oneToMany

Tags: java, dozer, mapstruct

Given the Source class as defined below:

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "peroson")
    List<Phone> phones
    // getters and setters
}
```

and the Phone class as defined below:

```
class Phone{
        private Long id;
        private String phoneNumber;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "person")
        private Person person;
        // getters and setters
    }
```

and DTO objects:

```
class PersonDTO{
        private String name;
        private int age;
        List<PhoneDTO> phones
        // getters and setters
    }

class PhoneDTO{
            private Long id;
            private String phoneNumber;
            private PersonDTO person;
            // getters and setters
        }
```

I have an interface :

```
@Mapper(uses={PersonMapper.class})
interface PhoneMapper{
    PhoneDTO toDto(Phone source);
    Phone toEntity(PhoneDTO source);
}

 @Mapper(uses={PhoneMapper.class})
    interface PersonMapper{
        PersonDTO toDto(Person source);
        Person toEntity(PersonDTO source);
    }
```

when I use `PeronMapper` or `PhoneMapper`  there is a recursive call, because `PersonMapper` use `PhoneMapper` and `PersonMapper` use `PhoneMapper`.

how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to avoid the recursion.

First option:

Avoid by explicitly ignoring in one of your mappers

Second option:

Use the `@Context` and write your own memoization. There is an example [mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles) in the mapstruct examples repo.

The idea is to have a `@Context`

```
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {
    private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();

    @BeforeMapping
    public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        return (T) knownInstances.get( source );
    }

    @BeforeMapping
    public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
        knownInstances.put( source, target );
    }
}
```

And then pass in an instance of this context to your mappers:

```
@Mapper(uses={PersonMapper.class})
interface PhoneMapper{
    PhoneDTO toDto(Phone source, @Context CycleAvoidingContext context);
    Phone toEntity(PhoneDTO source, @Context CycleAvoidingContext context);
}

@Mapper(uses={PhoneMapper.class})
interface PersonMapper{
    PersonDTO toDto(Person source, @Context CycleAvoidingContext context);
    Person toEntity(PersonDTO source, @Context CycleAvoidingContext context);
}
```

Of course the `CycleAvoidingMappingContext` can have more specified sources, instead of just `Object`. You can have one for `Person` and `PersonDTO` only for example. It is up to you how you want to implement it.

Edit:

When you have cyclic dependency between Mappers then the only solution is to use a dependency injection framework. The default MapStruct `Mappers` factory does not support cycles.

Comment: This solution is for another problem
A -> B -> A enties

Here the problem is the Mapper instance. Amapper  calls Bmapper but Bmapper uses also Amapper => recursive uses.
I've the same problem but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: You are right @Sum_Pie. I've added an edit to the question to clarify that

Comment: Ok, actually today I've solved the problem in this way:

`@Mapper(uses=B_Mapper.class)
A_Mapper {
}

interface B_Mapper{
A_Mapper mapA = Mappers.get(A_Mapper.class)
}`